# is it possible to have local only branches in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to have local branches in a local repo without having them appearing on a remote repository?

e.g.

```
Local Repo:

[default]
[fixes]
```

I'd like to merge the fixes branch into default and then push upto the remote repository **without** pushing the local [fixes] branch to the remote repo?

```
Remote Repo:

[default]
```

Comment: See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989262/discard-a-local-branch-in-mercurial-before-it-is-pushed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [LocalbranchExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LocalbranchExtension) exists but I never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

If you merge `fixes` into `default`, then `fixes` is part of the `default` history, and must be pushed as well. If you have two *separate* branch heads it is possible to push one without the other with `hg push -r <rev>`.